# Executing PowerShell command with parameters from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I try to execute some PowerShell commands with parameters from c#.

This works fine:

```cs
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
   PowerShellInstance.AddScript("param($param1); Get-ChildItem $param1");
   PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", "C:\\");

   Collection<PSObject> PSOutput =  PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

   foreach (var item in PSOutput)
   {
      if(item != null)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

But this does not work:

```cs
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
   PowerShellInstance.AddScript("param($param1); Get-ChildItem $param1");
   PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", "-Path C:\\");

   ...
}
```

Can someone help me to correct the last code. I would like to use the "-Path" parameter and later the "-Exclude" parameter like this in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C: -Exclude *.exe
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, I do not get the items from the command as expected

Comment: `$param1` will be passed as a string to `Get-ChildItem` and not as a parameter and value pair.  You might want to look at [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6), which can be used to pass on parameters in the way you are trying to do (see the `@PsBoundParameters` example in the link above)

Comment: Sorry, I try to use the @PsBoundParameters example in the link but I do not come to a solution. What exactly I have to write in the AddParameter method?